# make an angular app with js bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bookmarklet

I'm trying to make an angularjs app out of an site by clicking on a JS bookmarklet.

The problem is the ng-controller isn't recognize by angular and throws this error:

```
Error: Argument 'LDController' is not a function, got undefined
```

First i define ng-app and use angular.module with the same name, this works, i got `<html ng-app="bookmarklet">`.
Then I load an external file by the name of application.js. `app.controller('LDController', ..)` is defined in this file!

What i am doing wrong? here is the js bookmarklet code:

```
function loadApp() {
  document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].setAttribute('ng-app', 'bookmarklet');

  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.setAttribute('ng-controller', 'LDController');
  div.innerHTML = '';
  document.body.appendChild(div);

  var js = document.createElement('script');
  js.innerText = "var app = angular.module('bookmarklet', []);";
  document.body.appendChild(js);

  js = document.createElement('script');
  js.setAttribute('src', 'http://example.org/js/application.js');
  document.body.appendChild(js);
}

(function () {
  if (typeof angular === 'undefined') {
    js = document.createElement('script');
    js.setAttribute('src', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular.min.js');
    js.onload = loadApp;
    document.body.appendChild(js);
  }
  else {
    loadApp();
  }
}());
```

Comment: Angular treats `script` tags rather specially.  Have you seen the discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/H4haaMePJU0/discussion) where Igor talks about how the inclusion of jQuery could help?

Comment: hmm now i got the error away by using loadScripts from https://github.com/szabyg/vie-annotation-bookmarklet/blob/gh-pages/loader.js 

but now the app.run function doesn't work anymore, i load the js files in this order: angular.min.js, init.js, service.js, controller.js -> this is my init.js with app.run http://linkedmovie.hp.af.cm/js/init.js - in it there are 2 console.log, the first (app) makes an output the second in app.run doesn't ... why is that?

Comment: I've been thinking and you are manually initializing Angular by adding the `ng-app` directive. The prescribed method for doing this is to NOT insert `ng-app` and instead to call `angular.bootstrap` on the appropriate element after everything else is set up. So for instance:

angular.element(document).ready(function() {angular.bootstrap(document, ['bookmarklet']);}

Can you try this? There is more information [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)

Comment: wow thank you, that did it! now i've only have Access-Control-Allow-Origin errors left, but that's another problem ;) i will post the answer, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been thinking and you are manually initializing Angular by adding the `ng-app` directive. The prescribed method for doing this is to NOT insert `ng-app` and instead to call `angular.bootstrap` on the appropriate element after everything else is set up. So for instance:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['bookmarklet']);
}
```

There is more information [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)

Answer (score 2):

so i've worked it out, thanks to [Ram Rajamony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1860750/ram-rajamony)!

here is the solution as gist: https://gist.github.com/lpsBetty/5636338